# Inner Sphere of Capacitor is Grounded versus Rested on Insulated Stand

Tags: capacitance

My Question is about understanding the difference in Charge Distribution in a Spherical Capacitor in 2 Scenarios Here are the details of the Problem scenarios :-

If we have a Spherical Capacitor System in which there are 2 Spheres of Radius a & b then how does the Charge Distribute in these 2 scenarios namely Inner Surface is Grounded versus Inner Surface is Rested on an Insulated Rod compare.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKqNs.jpg]

[image]